# error in module paperclip (python) module not found copy() in paperclip?

Tags: python, copy, paperclip

```
File "C:\Users\Personal\PycharmProjects\pythonTutes\paperclip.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paperclip
  File "C:\Users\Personal\PycharmProjects\pythonTutes\paperclip.py", line 2, in <module>
    paperclip.Copy("hello world")
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'paperclip' has no attribute 'Copy' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Your own file is named `pyperclip.py`. rename it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the paperclip module, but when I want to copy something to my clipboard using python, I use:

```
text = "Hello World!"
subprocess.run("pbcopy", universal_newlines=True, input=text)
```

Run this, and then press `ctrl + v` or `command + v` to paste.